# Looping through 2d array removing elements, indexing error, python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to delete empty elements of a list named report info split but keep getting list out of range errors.

The list looks similar to this :

```
reportinfosplit = [[1,,g,5,44,f][1,5,4,f,g,,g]]
```

I have found many answers to this for 1d arrays but not 2d. Is there a way to prevent the index from going out of range? The list elements are not all the same size, and I thought that was the reason, but it kept happening after I made them the same length.

```
for i in range(len(reportinfosplit)):
    for j in range(len(reportinfosplit[i])):
        if(j<=len(reportinfosplit[i])):
            if reportinfosplit[i][j] == "":
                del reportinfosplit[i][j]
```

Comment: `if(j<=len(reportinfosplit[i]))` -> `if(j<len(reportinfosplit[i]))` might do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehensions

```
reportinfosplit = [[1,"",'g',5,44,'f'],[1,5,4,'f','g',"",'g']]

for ix, i in enumerate(reportinfosplit):
    reportinfosplit[ix] = [val for val in i if val != '']

print(reportinfosplit)
```

> [[1, 'g', 5, 44, 'f'], [1, 5, 4, 'f', 'g', 'g']]

Comment: I definitely like this solution and it works. I have always found list comprehensions difficult to read though, which is why I've had issues using them. I am currently learning python 3 transitioning from C++. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Yeah they definitely take a moment to get used to. This goes through each row. Then the list comprehension, creates a new list which includes all the values except those that are ''.

Comment: Can you tell me more about what it means by ix? Is x just another variable in the nested loop in this case? If it is, why is it so many people use x instead of j. I was always told to use i, j, k instead of x, y, z

Comment: @MakennaSophiaHerl the `for` loop with enumerate outputs both the index of the instance and the instance itself. These variables can have any name you desire. I chose `ix` for index and `i` for the item.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` to remove empty values from list

```
reportinfosplit = [[1,"","g",5,44,"f"],[1,5,4,"f","g","","g"]]
print([filter(None, i) for i in reportinfosplit])     #Python3 print([list(filter(None, i)) for i in reportinfosplit])
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 'g', 5, 44, 'f'], [1, 5, 4, 'f', 'g', 'g']]
```

Comment: Added snippet for python3. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `j` for `j<=len(reportinfosplit[i])`, which results in `j` being able to become as large as the current length of `reportinfosplit[i]` (which is possible, since the current length of `reportinfosplit[i]` changes). Try it like this:

```
for i in range(len(reportinfosplit)):
    for j in range(len(reportinfosplit[i])):
        if(j<len(reportinfosplit[i])):
            if reportinfosplit[i][j] == "":
                del reportinfosplit[i][j]
```